# How to start an external program on the Linux computer on which WWW-PHP is running, from non-CLI PHP?

Tags: linux, permissions, php, automation, www

I used to use Windows, with nginx and PHP. A localhost-only webserver for my own use. In my web "control panel", I had various very time-saving shortcuts. For example, I was able to click on various logged errors to bring up Notepad++, open the right file and go to the right line and column, on the same computer.

To do this, I simply ran `shell_exec('notepad++.exe blablabla 1 2 3');` (pseudo command) from the PHP file serving the page upon request.

Now that I instead run Linux (again with nginx and PHP), I'm suddenly unable to do this. No matter what I do, no program opens, and nothing whatsoever is logged about this. No errors. Nothing. It's simply ignored. I have tried everything, including:

```
shell_exec('kate blablabla 1 2 3 &');
shell_exec('mousepad blablabla &');
shell_exec('vivaldi &');

shell_exec('kate blablabla 1 2 3 >/dev/null &');
shell_exec('mousepad blablabla >/dev/null &');
shell_exec('vivaldi >/dev/null &');
```

Nothing whatsoever happens. I expected to see some kind of permission error or something, but there is nothing at all.

**Important**: All the commands above **work** when run from PHP CLI. I'm here talking about PHP-generated webpages requested from and served to a browser (on localhost).

I considered making an entry in the "sudoers" file for `www-data`, but I don't want to give root access to the user `www-data`. Besides, the commands don't require root powers, and I don't see any reason why `www-data` could not launch those programs just as well as my normal desktop user.

I have actually come up with an insane workaround, in which I essentially have a database table to which, instead of directly calling the functions in PHP, I send in the function calls and their arguments and store them as a JSON object, and then I have a CLI PHP daemon constantly looking for records in that table, fetch their data and execute the function calls from the CLI context where it works, and then delete the record. (So the table usually never has more than 1-2 entries at any given time, meaning it should be extremely "light" for being a database table.)

The downside of this workaround, besides being a lot of extra work and looking a bit ugly/silly, is that it can take several seconds before the action (function call) is actually carried out, depending on how much else my CLI daemon has to deal with. I suppose I could make a separate one which does nothing but loop for and execute such function calls, but even if I do, it just feels bad to be dependent entirely on the database for this and wasting resources looking for new records. It bugs me that I can't just avoid all that nonsense and just run the external programs like I used to.

Maybe I just "lucked out" when I discovered that this could be done on Windows without any problems, and it shouldn't be expected to be possible to do directly? Then again, I don't see why not.

I have already done all the work for the workaround, so it would be easy to keep it, but I would still like to hear if you can think of a more sensible way. If your solution is to run nginx as a different user, this is not possible for reasons. Also, this is Debian 12 and I use PHP-FPM.

Comment: This is better suited at StackOverflow, although not off-topic here. It's also a duplicate there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29272233/php-fpm-does-not-work-exec-system-shell-exec-only-cli Or a lot of duplicates, actually.

Comment: @Destroy666 Well, sadly, none of the "solutions" on that link are meaningful. And there is no "safe mode" anymore, even. :(